# showing the figure on two decimal places in google chart

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-visualization

I have a ComboChart with ControlWrapper, I want in my chart only I see the the figure on two decimal places, so I use formatter, this my code

```
 view: {

           columns: [

                     {

                //transform the numbers into strings, so the steppedArea series will work

              type: "string",

              calc: function (dt, row) {

                  var date = dt.getValue(row, 2);

                  var formatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({pattern:"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"});

                  return formatter.formatValue(date);

                  console.log(calc, typeof (calc));

              }

           },

           {

             type:"string",

    calc: function (dt, row) {

          var number = dt.getValue(row, 2);

          var number = dt.getValue(row, 3);

          var number = dt.getValue(row, 4);

             var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({fractionDigits:2});

          console.log(calc);

             return formatter.formatValue(number);

             }

           },   

           6,7]

       }
```

but I have this error :

One or more participants failed to draw()×

All series on a given axis must be of the same data type×

could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Answered over in the [Google Visualization API Discussion Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/oTaJoRY1qlQ), but to reprint here for folks with a similar problem:

You are returning a string value when you should be returning a number value.  If you want to format the data, you can return it as an object with "v" (value) and "f" (formatted value) properties:

```
{
    type: 'number',
    calc: function (dt, row) {
        var number = dt.getValue(row, 2);
        var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({fractionDigits:2});
        return {
            v: number,
            f: formatter.formatValue(number)
        };
    }
}
```